# Confusion about translation phases before preprocessing in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm reading a section about preprocessor in C Primer Plus and there is a paragraph which confuses me. It says that

> The compiler has to put a program through some translation phases
>   before jumping into preprocessing. The compiler starts its work by
>   mapping characters appearing in the source code to the source
>   character set.

Does this mean that the characters in the source code in mapped to some machine code which compiler can understand?

Comment: Machine code? I don;t think so, it's about character set, IMHO.

Comment: [This translation phase reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) might help.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the reference!